# How can i fade a background/object with black border?

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine, light

is there any way to ''fade out'' the background?i want the front part to stay the same, but i need to fix that 'background (with the red arrow) putting a Black hole/Black color

Is that possible?

[image]

Something like this:
(but backwards)

[image]

Comment: You can do that in the *Compositor* if you render the background as transparent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try blurring the background with a defocus node controlled with a mist pass.

Set your camera to display mist.

[image]

Enable mist on the render pass control.

[image]

Adjust the mist distance so it starts close to your camera and ends roughly in the area you want to blur.
[image]

Then in the compositor set the mist pass trough a color ramp node and use that to control the defocusing of the background.

[image]

If you move the sliders on the color ramp you can determine at what distance things start to blur, black will remain in focus, white is where the blur will start. The blur amount is determined by the defocus node max blur settings and the threshold values.

Comment: Wait...where do i find the compositor, is that the node editor? and where do i look at that kind of nodes?

Comment: The compositor is part of the node editor window. look closely at the icon on the image on the answer, the one that looks like two photos on top of each other. http://i.stack.imgur.com/ws8iy.png

Comment: I just did it! thank you :)
Now, how can i also 'fade' the part near to the character? (the exterior 'ring')? it looks to sharp :/
https://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/1907463_337706109751335_2166590446747741776_n.jpg?oh=dd39a2ac90e999a658679ac986e8f5ac&oe=55590DA2

Comment: Oh, i just changed the Threshold and it worked, thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

I think that the solution for you is in this link: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Tutorials/Composite_Nodes/Setups/Blur_the_Background
Although I don't know why, but it doesn't work for me. I tried many combinations and ended up with this kind of method (which is experimental). I don't think that this is the proper node setup, but the result is quite fine as you can see below:
[image]

Go to *Compositing Nodes* window and set up the nodes as shown below. Add a *Map Value* node (Add-->Vector-->*Map Value*) and experiment with its *Offset* and *Size* values.
[image]

As I said, I don't think that this is a proper method of doing this, but I wanted to share it with you. It may work for you, but if not, please tell me in comment and I'll delete this answer.

Answer (score 3):

After reading your question again i think this is how i would do it:

1. Turn on "Transparent" in the render panel
2. Go to the node editor and go to the renderlayer nodes and check "Use Nodes"
3. Then setup the following node chain:

[image]

This setup changes the Alpha of the all the pixels in the render based on how far from the camera the pixel is. The fade can be adjusted using the ColourRamp node.
Bear in mind that the Z value is based on the cameras clipping distances, if you change these you may have to tweak the bottom value in the math (devide) node.

Answer (score 2):

That can be done easily in the *Compositor* using only nodes. Have a look at this node group:

[image: Node setup]

They will output a nice background like this:

[image: Background]

All you need to do now is to add the render image over the top of it. To do that, update your nodes to look like this:

[image: Final nodes]

And voila! It works perfectly:

[image: End result]

You will of course want to play with color values etc, but the technique is the same.

You may find it works well to use a mixture of this and @ChristyJames answer.