# Make photo fade out to black in the middle of a circle

Tags: animation

I need to have a photo fade out to black in a tunnel effect.  Kind of like the edges are becoming all black and you only see the circular photo in the middle which then goes to full black.  Can't find the term for it and not sure if this program will do it.  Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Should be possible by animating a Vignette sort of effect

Comment: Would this allow me to have it stay as a gif?  I don't want it to turn into a video file.

Comment: Blender can't out put GIF's (?), but you can export the images as, say, PNG's and make a GIF in for instance GIMP (open first image, then open the rest of the images in the sequence as "Layers").

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39034/what-is-the-fastest-and-easiest-way-to-add-a-vignette-in-the-compositer-for-cycl and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24213/how-can-i-fade-a-background-object-with-black-border

Comment: and  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38689/how-do-i-rig-each-blade-to-fan-out-like-an-aperture-lens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the compositor add an image node and create an ellipse mask.
[image]

By animating the size of the mask (with and height) over time down to zero you can create an iris effect.

[image]

Animating the X and Y coordinates of the mask you can change where the center of the vignette ends:

[image]